# Как вырезать из текста картинку?

Tags: javascript

Предположим есть такая структура

```
 <div id="image">
    <img src="..." />
    Text
 </div>
```

Так вот надо оставить картинку без текста. Подскажите, как это можно сделать при помощи javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var d = document.getElementById('image');
d.innerHTML = d.innerHTML.match(/<img[^>]+>/ig);
```

Comment: Если помогло, ткните галку слева от ответа, чтоб вопрос не висел в неотвеченных.